# Keeping components horizontally aligned using a flow layout manager

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

For reasons I won't discuss in detail, I am limited to using a flow layout manager. The obvious problem with this and my necessity to keep components on the same line, is that it pushes components further down the frame is they surpass the panel edges.

Are there methods I can use to align components to make sure that labels and their corresponding text fields appear on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, the main problem is that the label and the input are separated (the label on the right side, and the input in the next line on the left).

One solution for that problem is the group the label and the input field into a sub panel, and add this sub panel to the main panel which uses the FlowLayout.

The code below illustrates this technique:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author acampos
 */
public class Main02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel dynamicPanel;
        JLabel dynamicLabel;
        JTextField dynamicInput;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Creates the panel that will contain the Label AND the Input
            dynamicPanel = new JPanel();
            // Creates the dynamic label
            dynamicLabel = new JLabel("Label " + i + ": ");
            // Creates the dynamic text field
            dynamicInput = new JTextField(10);
            // Adds the label and the text field to the dynamic panel
            dynamicPanel.add(dynamicLabel);
            dynamicPanel.add(dynamicInput);
            dynamicPanel.setSize(100, 100 );
            // Adds the dynamic panel to the main panel <-- HERE IS THE KEY
            mainPanel.add(dynamicPanel);
        }

        // Set the FlowLayout to the MAIN PANEL, so the dynamic panels
        // will 'flow' but the label and the text field will be kept together
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(3));
        // Adds the main panel (which contains the dynamic panels) to the main frame
    
        jFrame.add( mainPanel );
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setSize(600, 150);
        jFrame.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

When you run this code (yes, you can run it) and change the jFrame's size you see that the label and the input don't split anymore.